# Are there any modeling tools that can visually generate jpa or sql queries?

Tags: sql, jpa, code-generation, entity-bean

Does anyone know of a tool like [PowerArchitect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect) or [SquirrelSQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) or maybe eclipse plugin that lets you also generate jpa/sql queries?

Imagine you choosing your database, or your entity beans, and the modeling would reverse engineer your database/entity model, so that you could visually just choose the columns you wanted to select, and it would generate jpa or sql queries for you.

For instance choosing `A.b` and `X.y` would generate something like this:

```
select a.b, x.y from A a, X x join ......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse (more precisely the Data Tools Platform Project) has a **SQL Query Builder** built-in. Open a **SQL Scrapbook**,  **right-click** in it and select **Edit in SQL Query Builder**:

[alt text http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/2872/screenshot003xm.png](http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/2872/screenshot003xm.png)

This will open the SQL Query Builder:

[alt text http://img532.imageshack.us/img532/5943/screenshot004c.png](http://img532.imageshack.us/img532/5943/screenshot004c.png)

Then add tables, conditions, etc. There is a [Webinar](http://live.eclipse.org/node/678) showing it in action.

---

MyEclipse also has a [Visual SQL Query Builder](http://www.myeclipseide.com/htmlpages-func-display-pid-440.html). And I'm pretty sure other standalone universal clients support this visual query builder too.

---

For JPA, I'm not aware of any visual builder in Dali. This [has been mentioned](http://markmail.org/message/nqyo7iqekxfehp5k) in the past but I have no idea of the exact status (I don't use Dali actually). However, [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/08/0819_mutdosch/) mentions a **Visual JPQL query builder** in IBM Rational Application Developer.

Comment: Thanks. Such a nice great tool!

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly heavy-weight and non-free solution that requires significant investment of time to justify itself, but I believe [Database Visual Architect](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/dbva/) from Visual Paradigm will do what you're asking for.

Take a look at the [Generate SQL](http://resource.visual-paradigm.com/vpsuite2.2sp2/generate_sql.html) documentation for DB-VA to get a sense of whether it supports the operations and types of queries you're looking for.  If you can't fully assess its applicability from the docs, there's a free 30-day [trial](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/dbva.jsp) that might be worth a shot.

For what it's worth, I've used older versions of several of Visual Paradigm's products and they're definitely top-notch even if a little cumbersome at times.